# Speech to Text on UWP apps using Audio File as Input

Tags: visual-studio, audio, win-universal-app, winjs, speech-to-text

I am having troubles finding the answer for this question on web.

The project I am developing demands that I could save a recorded audio file, and, after that, transcribe the audio to text for finding interesting predefined keywords.

I am using the Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition framework, and it works fine when you are transcribing the speech during the recording process. I can't find, in the same framework, a function which I can use with an audio file as input.

Does anybody know a good approach for this problem? Or another [free] framework for Windows Apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For online recognition and in particular in JS projects you can use directly [Microsoft Cognitive Services](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/speech-api), that are behind online recognition in the SpeechRecognition in Windows. It is free under some limits.

In particular here is open sourced wrapped for JavaScript on GitHub:[Oxford.Speech.JS](https://github.com/Microsoft/ProjectOxford-ClientSDK/tree/master/Speech/Speech.JS). It can deal with both wav-files and microphone. Sample code is designed like a website, but I'm pretty sure you can easily convert it into a HTML/JS-based UWP app.

Comment: Oxford.Speech.JS is deprecated (gobbled up by Azure) and MCS only has a free _trial_ available.